# как получить командой time на linux время и ресурсы архивирования файла?

Tags: linux, время

Встретился такой пример

```
$ time -f "%U seconds CPU %P" gzip -c9 BIGNULL > BIGNULL.gz
```

должно по идее выводить так: `112.66 seconds CPU 95%`

на ubuntu 16.10 работать не хочет, ругается `-f: command not found`
как заставить работать?
или какая-то библиотека нужна?

Answer (score 1):

В `man time` есть хорошая фраза "многие shell (например bash) имеют собственную команду time, с меньшей функциональностью, используйте явное указание пути к time, что бы использовать описываемую тут команду". У вас именно тот случай, посмотрите есть ли у вас в системе time и где она лежит, попробуйте `/bin/time` или `/usr/bin/time`. (у себя в gentoo я ее вообще не нашел). А встроенная в bash никаких ключей не знает и ведет себя, как вы описали.